# How can I specify IP and ports for a hostname in the Windows hosts file?

Tags: windows, ip-address, localhost

I want to specify host names with two different ports in the Windows `hosts` file.

Is there a way to do it?  Or is it not allowed by Windows itself?

I have been wasting my time searching for the solution for the last 8 hours.

Is it possible to specify ports in the host file, `hosts`? E.g.: `127.0.0.1:80` and `127.0.0.1:9211`

Comment: The HOSTS file only associates names with IP addresses, not IPs+port(s).  Do check superuser.com, however, by describing more of the specifics of what you are trying to do (is this for a web server etc. etc.) as there are many ways to achieve this type of mapping, but always depending on specifics at hand.

Comment: You need NGNIX or Apache HTTP server as a proxy server for forwarding http requests to appropriate application -> which listens particular port

Answer (score 26):

Simply use IP addresses without ports. Example:

```
192.168.2.50  example.com
```

Then, to access 192.168.2.50:5555 from your browser (or other program):

```
http://example.com:5555/
```

The `hosts` file can be found at:

**Linux** `/etc/hosts`

**Windows**: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: It will be helpful to add both *path* and *the name of the file* to be edited.

Comment: Can you possibly update with the reason for NOT specifying the port number when editing the file at ***`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`*** ?

Comment: That's covered in the other answers.

Answer (score 19):

You cannot associate a port number with a hostname mapped to an IP in the hosts file. You can achieve this with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) though using FiddlerScript:

```
if (oSession.HostnameIs("somesite.com")){
    oSession.bypassGateway = true;
    oSession["x-overrideHost"] = "1.2.3.4:8080";
}
```

Comment: Nice suggestion for tech users. Just to clarify, 
1) First install Fiddler
2) Then open it and go to Rules Menu and pick Customize Rules option ( or press Ctrl + R on windows ). This will open a JS file in notepad. 
3) Find static function OnBeforeRequest and paste the script suggested by @John inside its body.

Also HostNameIs will not work, it should be HostnameIs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you aware of any open source alternative (james, owasp zap, or other) which can be used to the same effect?

Answer (score 18):

- The `hosts` file is for resolving hostnames to IP addresses only
- If you do not specify a port as part of a URL, e.g. `<protocol>://<hostname>[:<port>][/path]`, your browser will use the default port for the protocol: `HTTP/80, HTTPS/443, FTP/21`

#### Example Problem Scenario

1. Applications typically set their servers to the same default IP address `127.0.0.1` (aka `localhost`, *defined in the **hosts** file)*.
2. To allow routing traffic to the right server when multiple servers share the same IP, applications typically allow you to modify their port if needed, but not their IP address.

   - *"if"* you could change the servers IP address to another in the [loopback reserved address space](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6890#page-7) `127.0.0.0/8`, then you probably wouldn't be attempting to set ports in the **hosts** file

#### Possible Solution

You can work around this using Windows' built-in networking tool **`netsh`** as a port proxy.

---

#### Overview

```
http://example.app
|                                 <--browser defaults to HTTP port 80
+-> http://example.app:80          
    |                             <--Hostname resolved to IP by Hosts File
    +-> http://127.65.43.21:80    
        |                         <--Link by netsh Utility
        +-> http://127.0.0.1:8081
```

#### Actions

1. Start your app's HTTP server on a custom port: `localhost:8081`
2. Add a line in the **hosts** file that maps a free IP address to the app's hostname:

   - Example: `127.65.43.21     example.app`
   - I suggested `127.65.43.21` but any free address in the subnet `127.0.0.0/8` can be used
   - Verify that `127.65.43.21:80` isn't already in use by another service.  If it is, use a different IP. Check using: `netstat -a -n -p TCP | FINDSTR "LISTENING"`
3. Add the following network configuration, using `netsh`:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 listenaddress=127.65.43.21 connectport=8081 connectaddress=127.0.0.1
```

4. Try to access the server at `http://example.app`

#### Notes:

- These commands/file modifications need to be executed with **Admin rights**
- [netsh portproxy needs IPv6 libraries](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555744), even just to use `v4tov4`. Typically, these will be installed by default, otherwise, install them with `netsh interface ipv6 install`

---

You can ***see the entry*** you have added with the command:

```
netsh interface portproxy show v4tov4
```

You can ***remove the entry*** with the following command:

```
netsh interface portproxy delete v4tov4 listenport=80 listenaddress=127.65.43.21
```

---

#### Links to Resources:

- [Using Netsh](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490939.aspx)
- [Netsh commands for Interface IP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738592(v=ws.10).aspx)
- [Netsh commands for Interface Portproxy](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc731068(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_1)
- [Windows Port Forwarding Example](http://woshub.com/port-forwarding-in-windows/)

*Note: this answer is a duplication of my answer discussed in [this similar question/answer on stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652948/using-port-number-in-windows-host-file)*